# MacOS path formatting of the dir

Tags: swift, macos

I have the following paths (they are an example), I would like to be able to get the result below.

```
/Users/nameUser
/Users
/Users/nameUser/Downloads/nameDir
/Users/nameUser/Documents/nameDir
/Users/nameUser/Desktop/nameDir/nameProject
```

Result:

```
/Users/nameUser
/Users/
~/Downloads/nameDir
~/Documents/nameDir
~/Desktop/nameDir/nameProject
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FileManager` can provide the home directory path. So you can then check if a path starts with it, and if so, replace it with a tilde.

```
func pathWithTilde(_ path: String) -> String {
    let homeDir = FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser.path + "/"
    if path.starts(with: homeDir) {
        return "~/" + path[homeDir.endIndex...]
    }
    return path
}
```

**Update**

Turns out this already exists as a method of `NSString` (though it will also convert `/Users/nameUser` to `~`). A little `String` extension help hide the `NSString` specifics.

```
extension String {
    var abbreviatingWithTildeInPath: String {
       (self as NSString).abbreviatingWithTildeInPath
    }
}

print("/Users/nameUser/Downloads/nameDir".abbreviatingWithTildeInPath)
```

Comment: It seems to work, I was thinking of doing something like this:
`let path = projectPath.components(separatedBy:"/")`

If the number of elements is greater than 3, then I remove the first 3 elements and put the tilde.
If it was not so, I would leave it alone.

Comment: Which of the two tips?